# counting progress in a while loop

Tags: python

I have a `while(1)` loop that runs forever until stopped.

I want to track the progress of the `while` loop while it is running

Here is the loop implementation

```
counter = 0

multiple = 1000

while(1):
  counter += 1

  if(condition):
     print "Reached: " + counter
```

I want to print how close I am to the multiple at `counter = #some value`

So desired output could be

```
10%
20%
30%
40%
50%
60%
70%
80%
90%
Reached 1000
10%
20%
30%
40%
50%
60%
70%
80%
90%
Reached 2000
.
.
.
```

How do I implement the `condition` ?

EDIT : I have used a very easy number `1000` but I want to do it for any kind of factor number and track how close I am to the next multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
counter = 0
prec = multiple//10
while 1:

    if not counter % multiple:
        print "Reached: ", counter

    elif not counter % prec:
        print "{0:.0f}%".format((counter%multiple*1.0/multiple)*100)

    counter += 1
```

Comment: I don't know why I am being down-voted, but your solution has worked. Thank you.